# How to determine when user has cancelled downloading file from web site --- tr:fileDownloadActionListener

Tags: java, jsf, download, trinidad

I'm using JSF 1.2 with Trinidad Library

In my xhtml file in order to enable downloading I'm using `<tr:fileDownloadActionListener`>.

How can I know when a user cancel downloading the file ?